# How to get around strategic eager loading in Datamapper?

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper

I'm processing a ton of book records (12.5 million) with Ruby and Datamapper. On rare occasion I need to grab associated identifiers for a particular book record, but Datamapper is creating a select statement grabbing all the associated identifiers for all the book records. The query take more than 2 minutes.

http://datamapper.org/why.html

The help document says this is "Strategic Eager Loading" and...

"The idea is that you aren't going to load a set of objects and use only an association in just one of them. This should hold up pretty well against a 99% rule.

When you don't want it to work like this, just load the item you want in it's own set. So DataMapper thinks ahead. We like to call it "performant by default". This feature single-handedly wipes out the "N+1 Query Problem"."

However, how do you load an item in it's own set? I can't seem to find a way to specify that I really only want to query the identifiers for one of the book records.

Comment: Okay, I think I've figured out the problem and a workaround. In order for associations for record to be selected without selecting all associations, you have to originally select the record with Record.get(<key>). I was selecting the record with Record.first(<unique column>). Though the results are the same, Datamapper subsequent association queries are different. Datamapper will grab all assocations when you use Record.first and Record.last as if you used Record.all.

Comment: My workaround is to query twice. First I use record = Record.first(<unique column>). Then I grab the record again using record = Record.get(<key>). That solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this issue, it might be because you are using Model.first() rather than Model.get(). See my comments under the question too.

As of DM 1.1.0...

Example using Model.first:

```
# this will create a select statement for one book record
book = Books.first(:author => 'Jane Austen')

# this will create select statement for all isbns associated with all books
# if there are a lot of books and identifiers, it will take forever
book.isbns.each do |isbn|
  # however, as expected it only iterates through related isbns
  puts isbn
end
```

This is the same behavior as using Book.all, and then selecting the associations on one

Example using Model.get:

```
# this will create a select statement for one book record
book = Books.get(2345)

# this will create select statement for book with a primary key of 2345
book.isbns.each do |isbn|
  puts isbn
end
```